# Grid-based lighting engine

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, shadow, lighting

I am trying to create a grid-based shadow engine using JavaScript. My algorithm shades squares based on whether their position is 'behind' a block, relative to a light source.

This is my algorithm so far: https://jsfiddle.net/jexqpfLf/

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 400;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var light_x = 90;
var light_y = 110;

var block_x = 120;
var block_y = 120;

requestAnimationFrame(render);
function render() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var vec1_x = block_x - light_x;
    var vec1_y = block_y - light_y;
    var vec1_mag = Math.sqrt(vec1_x * vec1_x + vec1_y * vec1_y);

    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += 10)
        for (var y = 0; y < canvas.width; y += 10) {
            var vec2_x = x - light_x;
            var vec2_y = y - light_y;
            var vec2_mag = Math.sqrt(vec2_x * vec2_x + vec2_y * vec2_y);
            var dotproduct = vec1_x * vec2_x + vec1_y * vec2_y;

            var angle = Math.acos(dotproduct / (vec1_mag * vec2_mag));

            if (vec2_mag > vec1_mag && angle < Math.PI / 8 / vec1_mag * 10)
                ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
        }

    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(light_x, light_y, 10, 10);

    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(block_x, block_y, 10, 10);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.which == 65)
        light_x -= 10;
    if (e.which == 68)
        light_x += 10;
    if (e.which == 87)
        light_y -= 10;
    if (e.which == 83)
        light_y += 10;
}
```

Unfortunately, as you can see in the demonstration, I'm finding some angles problematic. Some squares which should be shaded are left unshaded. This happens for some angles and distances (between the light source and the block) but not others. For example, placing the light source at (60, 90) shows these artifacts as well.

I am using the vectors LP (from light to point) and LB (from light to block), taking their dot product and dividing by the product of their magnitudes to find the shading angle, then scaling this angle depending on the distance between the block and light source.

Could these artifacts be due to rounding errors? Or is there a problem with the algorithm itself? Any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. You're not gonna like this one.

It's a floating point math issue.

What's the value of `Math.acos(1.000000000000000)`?

`0`.

Whats the value of `Math.acos(1.0000000000000003)`?

`NaN`.

That's annoying, isn't it?

At some values, your `dotproduct` is `6000` and your `(vec1_mag * vec2_mag)` is `5999.999999999999`, leading to the issue above.

Changing `(vec1_mag * vec2_mag)` to `Math.round(vec1_mag * vec2_mag)` will solve your problem.

**While we're staring at this fiddle together** you should know that there's another bug:

```
for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += 10) {
    for (var y = 0; y < canvas.width; y += 10) {
```

You use `canvas.width` here twice. I imagine the second one ought to be `canvas.height`, so make sure what you wrote there is what you want.

[Working fiddle for you!](http://jsfiddle.net/XCMkU/1/)